# Mongoose - Push objects into nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to push every object inside of an array into an array using Mongoose.

This is an example of what the structure of my playlist collection looks like:

```
playlist: {
    userName: 'user-name',
    userId: 'user-id',
    playlistArray: [
        {
            playlistName: 'playlist1',
            playlistSongs: [
                { title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
            ],
        },
        {
            playlistName: 'playlist2',
            playlistSongs: [
                { title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```

I want to push the following array of objects into the `playlistSongs` array that also has `playlistName: 'playlist2'` within the same object

```
[
    { title: '1', duration: 123, uri: 'a' },
    { title: '2', duration: 456, uri: 'b' },
    { title: '3', duration: 789, uri: 'c' },
]
```

So the result would look like this:

```
playlist: {
    userName: 'user-name',
    userId: 'user-id',
    playlistArray: [
        {
            playlistName: 'playlist1',
            playlistSongs: [
                { title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
            ],
        },
        {
            playlistName: 'playlist2',
            playlistSongs: [
                { title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { title: '1', duration: 123, uri: 'a' },
                { title: '2', duration: 456, uri: 'b' },
                { title: '3', duration: 789, uri: 'c' },
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```

Here is my code trying to update the model:

```js
const newPlaylistSongs = [
    { title: '1', duration: 123, uri: 'a' },
    { title: '2', duration: 456, uri: 'b' },
    { title: '3', duration: 789, uri: 'c' },
];

await playlist
.updateOne(
    {},
    {
        $addToSet: {
            'playlistArray.$[pl].playlistSongs': {
                $each: {
                    newPlaylistSongs
                }
            },
        },
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {
                'pl.playlistName':'playlist2',
            },
        ],
    }
)
.catch(console.error);
```

But I have gotten this error:

> MongoServerError: The argument to $each in $addToSet must be an array but it was of type object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) is expected with an `array` value.

```
$each: []
```

```js
await playlist
.updateOne(
    {},
    {
        $addToSet: {
            'playlistArray.$[pl].playlistSongs': {
                $each: newPlaylistSongs
            },
        },
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {
                'pl.playlistName':'playlist2',
            },
        ],
    }
)
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yT5NDiurb-Q)

Comment: Ah, I see, but how would I go about inserting the `newPlaylistSongs ` variable into the collection? since it's already an array.

Edit: never mind, I misread your solution. Thank you!